# $X^2+p$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I have to prove that $X^2+p$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ with $p$ a prime number. What I thought was that $X^2+p$ has no roots in $\mathbb{Q}$ so I cant factor it in polynomials of degree 1. Is this actually correct, because I never used the fact that $p$ is a prime number. If this is wrong, can you give me some hints? Thanks.

Comment: One name: Eisenstein. Of course the fact that it has no rational roots works too, you used the fact that $p$ is prime when you said that it has no rational roots (it works more general, for $p$ not a perfect square, on the other hand, Eisenstein works for higher degrees than $2$).

Comment: An alternate solution: You know what the roots have to be over the algebraic closure, right? Factor and show that these roots aren't in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer this is exercise is in the chapter before introducing eisenstein polynomials, so I think you dont need those.

Comment: @Badshah I meant Eisenstein's irreducibility criterion.

Comment: @KReiser that is what I did, could you read the post again?

Comment: @DanielFischer everything about eisenstein is in the next chapter.

Comment: The polynomial $X^2+a$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ if $a$ is positive (and for plenty of negative $a$ too).

Comment: Okay, then as I said, you use that $p$ is prime (more general, not a perfect square), when you determine that the polynomial has no rational roots. And, seeing André's comment, I swear I saw $X^2 - p$, duh.

Comment: @DanielFischer oke thanks. I was confused about this exercise because of the prime $p$, because my argument works for all positive integers.

Comment: @Badshah Yes, with $+$, positive is enough, I thought it was $-$, sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is correct... assuming that by "prime number" you mean "*positive* prime integer", and provided you realize that any reducible quadratic must have a root. (And, of course, you know *why* $x^2+p$ doesn't have any roots)

The same argument would work for $x^2 - p$... but in that case you *would* have to use the fact $p$ is a prime. (How else would you know it doesn't have any roots?)

(note: -2, -3, -5, and so forth are all prime integers. It is a common *convention*, though, that we restrict term to just the positive 'representatives')